# Dungeon Defenders: Transfer character (PS3)?

Tags: ps3, dungeon-defenders

I have been playing Dungeon Defenders with 4 players on 1 PS3. We would like to transfer 2 characters to another PS3 (which has a different PSN account) so we can "LAN" play together.

How can we transfer the characters (or save file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

To my knowledge, the only way to transfer Dungeon Defender PS3 game saves is to use the Backup/Restore utility and move it to another console, or with PSN+ I believe you can upload it and download it elsewhere. Both methods will keep it tied to the same PSN account.

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: I see... The DD wiki said `The PC, PS3 and mobile device can share character save files. XBOX 360 will not support this.`

Comment: You missed the "Coming soon" part when you quoted that line.

Comment: That was edited into it a week after the game came out, misrepresenting what the game really featured.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of getting your character to another PS3 would be to get a save from online, then learn to mod.

You can change the stats/level of players. Most people who do this end up making a level 2,000,000. With all stats maxed as high as possible.

A legit player could modify every to be just like their character. Even the equipment, if you find a loaded save file. Just don't forget to change the serial numbers on the equipment you plan to use.

You risk it dupe/disappearing otherwise

Comment: This is not a answer that says "the same" as the accepted one?